# How do I load files in Edwin

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, edwin

This might be a stupid question but I cannot figure this out for the life of me nor can I find a reference online which answers my question.

I have been using Edwin (this is my first time using Emacs) to follow along with the MIT Opencourseware 6.001 class and I cannot figure out how to load a file.

Upon startup, I type C-x C-f to make a new file "test.scm". I then input some Scheme code and type C-x C-s to save it.

But then if I close Edwin, start it back up,and type C-x C-f test.scm, I just get a blank slate. If instead I type M-x dired, scroll to test.scm and hit RET, I still get a blank slate. The file takes up some space in windows so I don't think the issue is with saving but rather loading (especially since I similarly cannot load the premade .scm files provided by MIT)

I am running MIT/GNU Scheme on Windows 7 if that matters...

Comment: Welcome to Programmers. Please take a moment to read the site's [FAQ] where you'll find good information to asking questions here. This question is off-topic. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on StackOverflow. If your question has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers. Please don't re-ask this on SO as this can be migrated.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize that StackOverflow (with no suffix) was already for programming. I will migrate the question (once I figure out how)

Answer (score 3):

There is an open bug report for this: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?35250.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late for a timely answer. This is how I do it:

1. Create the function in a file with Notepad (or its better cousin, Notepad++)
2. Save the file with the .scm extention. Place it somewhere you can remember.
3. load said file this way (do not forget the double \\): `(load "c:\\path_to_your_folder\\your_file.scm")`
4. Now you have access to your function.

Comment: The main downside to this method is that it doesn't open a new buffer for editing the loaded code from Edwin.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the version of Edwin as the bug report said above,and the bug about Edwin can't open a file is actually disappeared.However,there is a new question,in some times the Ctrl key has not an effect.Therefore, if this bug is not very important to you,the best way is still to use this new version.